# I am trying to use a SUMPRODUCT and IMPORTRANGE formula

Tags: google-sheets

This formula works in my original google sheet, but I want to move this to a new workbook to import from the original.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($O10<='Daily Receiving'!$D$1:$CO$1)*($A$2>='Daily Receiving'!$D$1:$CO$1))*('Daily Receiving'!$A$3:$A$1306=$A10)*'Daily Receiving'!$D$3:$CO$1306)
```

Here is one version I have tried and I get an error that says array arguments to multiply are of different size.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($O10<=(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1"))*($A$2>=(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1")))*((IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet","Daily Receiving!$a$3:$a$1306")=$A10)*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet","Daily Receiving!$d$3:$cd$1306"))))))
```

Comment: Consider 1) posting examples of spreadsheet to examine 2) using MMULT instead of SUMPRODUCT, it will give you more precise error message 3) maybe the arrays imported are in fact of a different size - smaller?

Comment: I solved it !! Thank you !!

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(((IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1")<=$A$2)*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1")>=$O10))*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets","Daily Receiving!$a$3:$a$1306")=$A10)*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets","Daily Receiving!$D$3:$CO$1306")))

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1")<=$A$2)*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheets‌​","Daily Receiving!$D$1:$CO$1")>=$O10))*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet‌​s","Daily Receiving!$a$3:$a$1306")=$A10)*(IMPORTRANGE("httpspreadsheet‌​s","Daily Receiving!$D$3:$CO$1306")))
```